# Is it possible to manage read/write requests on AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-replication, rds

We are planning to create a read replica on our MySql Database on RDS but we want to manage this on AWS. Does AWS has a solution that manages requests and redirect them if write to the master otherwise to the read replica?

Comment: Some `SELECTs` are used in support of writes, hence must be on the same server, even in the same transaction.  Beware of any tool that "splits" those `SELECTs` out.

Answer (score 0):

I think [AWS Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) for MySQL is your best bet. It's quite flexible, you can have multi-master or read replicas.

Alternate a fairly new feature "RDS MySQL multi-az with two readable standbys" which you can see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/multi-az/) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/readable-standby-instances-in-amazon-rds-multi-az-deployments-a-new-high-availability-option/).

Your question is fairly high level. If it had more detail I may have been able to refine the answer a bit more.